# Can't associate product and category correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

everybody. I'm trying to associate every product with his category. But there are some errors.

So, at first.
Here is my product and category migrations:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table :products do |t|
          t.belongs_to :categoty, index: true
          t.string :title
          t.string :category
          t.text :description
          t.string :image_url
          t.decimal :price, precision: 8, scale: 2
          t.timestamps
      end
   end
end


class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.references :product
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Both of them have associations in models (`belongs_to` for product and `has_many` for category).

And I have made the form to link products with this category:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.collection_select :category, Category.all, :id, :name %>
</div>
```

And when I'm trying to save the product there is the error:
Category(#XXXX) expected, got String(#XXXX).

So, what am I doing wrong?

Also, here is my controller.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController


    before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


      # GET /products
      # GET /products.json
      def index
        @products = Product.all
      end

      # GET /products/1
      # GET /products/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /products/new
      def new
        @product = Product.new
      end

      # GET /products/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /products
      # POST /products.json
      def create
        @product = Product.new(product_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @product.save
            format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /products/1
      # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @product.update(product_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /products/1
      # DELETE /products/1.json
      def destroy
        @product.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_product
          @product = Product.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def product_params
          params.require(:product).permit(:title, :category, :description, :image_url, :price)
        end
    end
```

Comment: `belongs_to :category` will add c`ategory_id` in products table which will make category `has_many :products` relation successfully. We don't need `references :product`  in category table.

Comment: Thank you for your attention! Now I know. But I still have an error.

Comment: Please share your controller action to get clear picture of how you are calling save

Comment: You have `:category` attribute of `String` type in the `Product` model. Is it really necessary if there is also a `Category` model related? Maybe it is the reason of the exception raised.

Comment: @Mareq is right. Make it category_id `<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>`. and add that into `params.require(:product).permit(:title, :category_id,....` too.

Comment: I added my controller. So, I changed it to "category_id", but there is new error: undefined method `category_id'. Thanks everybody for yours attention!

Answer (score 0):

In your database migration file you have the field `categoty` and you are using `category_id` in controller. Just need to change the field to `category` in database to make sure it is associated to the correct model.

Comment: Really! It works! Sorry.... buuuuuuut there is another problem when I'm tring to show up  <%= @product.category.name %>  there is the error "no such column: categories.product_id: SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."product_id" = ?" so what I forgot to add?

Comment: Can you put your code in these models so I can help you check the problem with association? BTW, I think if there is just `1-N` relationship between these two models, you don't have to add `product_id` in `categories` table.

Comment: Of course. Category model: 
`class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
end
`
product code:
`class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one         :category
end`

Comment: I think change it to `belongs_to :category` in your `Product` model will fix it.

Comment: Really! Thanks for answering my stupid questions! I remeber your kindness forever!

Comment: And another thing. I'm so sorry for my questions. But it doesn't show me product category when I'm using `<%= @product.category %>`, and when I'm using  `<%= @product.category.name %>` there is the error on page.
So, what variable should I use to show up product's category?